# How to add local .tgz file with Yarn 2?

Tags: yarnpkg, offline, yarnpkg-v2

I am trying to install a module onto an offline computer using Yarn 2.

I have the `.tgz` file of the NPM module. It looks like it can be done with Yarn 1.x but does not appear to work with Yarn 2.

I put the file `lowdb-1.0.0.tgz` into the root of the project folder for testing and tried these which did not work (project is configured for Yarn 2):

`yarn add lowdb-1.0.0.tgz`

```
YN0027: lowdb-1.0.0.tgz@unknown can't be resolved to a satisfying range
YN0001: RequestError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.yarnpkg.com
...
```

`yarn add ./lowdb-1.0.0.tgz`

```
YN0000: Resolution step
YN0013: lowdb@file:./lowdb-1.0.0.tgz::locator=reaction%40workspace%3A. can't be found in the cache and will be fetched
YN0001: RequestError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.yarnpkg.com
...
```

`yarn add file:./lowdb-1.0.0.tgz`

```
Internal Error: Invalid descriptor (file:./lowdb-1.0.0.tgz)
...
```

Is this possible to do with Yarn 2? Or is there another way to install modules directly onto an offline computer using downloaded assets/bundles/tgz using Yarn 2?

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/add/

```
yarn add $( pwd )/lowdb-1.0.0.tgz
```